Using openid-connect access token and getting 403 in postman and 401 in logs
My keycloak is on 8080 and GeoServer is running on 8081. I have setup authentication using openid connect.
I've set the openid-adapter using the below configuration from my screenshot. 
I've added openid-adapter to filter chain for /rest/** endpoint as below:
   
Whenever I get the access token from POST http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
and use it as a bearer token to GET http://localhost:8081/geoserver/rest/security/acl/layers
I get the below 401 error in log.
17 Jul 15:59:17 INFO   [geoserver.filters] - [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] "GET /geoserver/web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.security.web.auth.AuthenticationPage?37&filter=false" took 74ms
17 Jul 16:06:50 ERROR  [geoserver.security] - Oauth2 OIDC - an error occurred during token validation.  Most likely the token has expired or is invalid/modified.  401 Unauthorized: "{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token verification failed"}"
Postman returns 403 error. This is the decoded jwt:
{
  "exp": 1721137525,
  "iat": 1721137465,
  "jti": "5c9a4db7-4093-409d-a584-7755d1937c8f",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/realms/master",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "c2250bd0-596a-4eb1-a774-815c77f90efc",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "geoserver-client",
  "session_state": "2dd5ea76-aea8-4d4b-9ddc-2c8ae7755237",
  "acr": "1",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "default-roles-master",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "geoserver-client": {
      "roles": [
        "ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  
}

Can someone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?

This was just a matter of setting the entire attribute for role source instead of just roles

